# UI Framework (Javascript, CSS)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a free and open-source UI framework, similar to jQuery UI, but with more features and solid/clean CSS. Any links? :)

Comment: If your willing to pay try [`ExtJS`](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/). It's simply a highly polished, flexible UI project. And compared to the cost of many Microsoft tools it's worth seriously considering.

Comment: If you don't specify which feature you would like to see and provide a definition for "solid/clean CSS" it's hard to answer (very broad question IMHO).

Comment: Well... a free and open-source alternative to ExtJS would be what i have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The only other jQuery one I know of is [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html).

it's not very good though

Answer (score 1):

YUI is probably the most documented and usable (arguably) UI library out there. I would take YUI over jQuery UI anytime. It has the best documentation and best [graded browser support](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/).

If you are starting a new project using YUI, go with YUI3.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/